# Fit of increasing sinusoidal function

Tags: trigonometry, curve-fitting, smoothing, skew, amplitude

I want to make a sinusoidal fit to my data. I got it working for a constant amplitude, see the Figure below and my code:

[image]

Besides that, my data is also slightly skewed to the right. Is it possible to encorporate this as well in to fit? See below the code on how far I got.

```
def Fit_Sine(tt, yy):

    tt = np.array(tt)
    yy = np.array(yy)

    ff = np.fft.fftfreq(len(tt), (tt[1]-tt[0]))   # assume uniform spacing
    Fyy = abs(np.fft.fft(yy))
    guess_freq = abs(ff[np.argmax(Fyy[1:])+1])   # excluding the zero frequency "peak", which is related to offset
    guess_amp = np.std(yy) * 2.**0.5
    guess_offset = np.mean(yy)
    guess_phase = 0.
    guess_damping = 1.5
    guess = np.array([guess_amp,  2.*np.pi*guess_freq, guess_phase])

    def sinfunc(t, A, w, p):  return A *  np.sin(w*t + p)

    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(sinfunc, tt, yy, p0=guess)
    A, w, p = popt
    f = w/(2.*np.pi)
    fitfunc = lambda t: A  * np.sin(w*t + p)

    res = {"amp": A, "omega": w, "phase": p, "freq": f,
           "period": 1./f, "fitfunc": fitfunc, "maxcov": np.max(pcov), "rawres": (guess,popt,pcov)}

    x_fit = np.arange(0, len(tt))
    fit = res["fitfunc"](x_fit)

    return fit
```

The reason for this is that I want to smooth out the bump in the top:

[image]

Other suggestions for achieving this are also welcome.

Regards,

Dante